# How can I avoid after_save getting call on destroy for particular method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am a beginner in rails, I want to avoid after_save getting called on destroy for a particular method without using `upload.delete`. I want to use this with `upload.destroy` so that validations will not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in model

```
after_save :some_method, unless: lambda{ |obj| obj.marked_for_destruction? }
```